# import normalize in rails asset-pipeline with esbuild

Tags: css, sass, asset-pipeline, normalize

`application.sass.scss` in rails asset-pipeline doesn't recognize normalize import from node_modules.

this is import I am using `@import "~normalize.css/normalize.css";`.

this is the build script

```
"build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules",
```

why does it not work?